# Accidentally submitted an incorrect edit but would like to correct immediately

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I just edited an answer's code snippet.

I realized I used one wrong word. I really would like the change to be accepted as I am looking to rack up points.

Once it gets rejected, which it will because of the accidental wording, what's the best course of action I should follow? Should I immediately re-edit with the correct wording?

Comment: I ended up re-editing again straight after. My assumption is that as soon as the first one is rejected, the second one on the queue (in all probability, mine) will be reviewed. (Most probably by another person).

Comment: "I really would like the change to be accepted as I am looking to rack up points." - bit of a tip from an old hand. *Edits* are a terrible way to get rep, and semi trivial edits are a bit meh. The fastest way to get rep is good answers.

Answer (score 15):

**No worries!**

If your first edit has not yet been accepted, you can edit as often as you want and it will overwrite as well as override your previous edit.